# Get value using mine.get from a ordered dictionary in state.sls

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a mine defined in pillar to get the ip of a salt minion. When I use the mine in a salt state I get a dictionary. Is there a way to filter out and get the first item from it.

Here is my mine which I have defined in a pillar:

```
    ip_add:
      - mine_function: grains.get
      - ipv4
```

Here is my state file:

```
{% set id = 'aws-vm1' %}
{% set addrs =  salt['mine.get'](id, 'ip_add') %}

{% for key in salt['mine.get'](id, 'ip_add')  %}
Test:
  file.append:
    - name: C:\test
    - text: {{addrs}}
```

The output i get is :
`OrderedDict([('aws-vm1', ['10.93.143.235', '127.0.0.1'])])`

I want to get the first ip so that I can share it between minions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a work around. I get the list of IPs from the mine

```
aws-vm1:
    ----------
    aws-vm1:
        - 10.93.143.235
        - 127.0.0.1
```

and grab the first value by `{{ip[0]}}`  which is the private IP I want.

```
{% set id = 'aws-vm1' %}
 
# Returns a dict OrderedDict
{% set ip_list  =  salt['mine.get'](id, 'ip_add') %} 


{% set ip=  ip_list.values() | first %}

Test:
  file.append:
    - name: C:\test
    - text: {{ip[0]}}
```

Comment: I think it can be refactored but I am not sure how to do it in Jinja. Please comment if anyone knows.